# How to replace a string between two commas in linux using sed

Tags: linux

```
execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(91, 129031, 958408630);          Lowes
```

From the above statement I am trying to get the content between the first comma and second comma i.e., 129031 and replace it with a new string which is passed as a parameter to the script. For now let's replace with N . I tried the following sed command ended up getting an error. Could someone please help?

```
04:24:01 Tue Sep 19 [serviceb@LQASRDSBMST002V:~/isops/tmp] cat Navya | sed 's/,^.\{*\},/N/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: Invalid content of \{\}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$: echo "start,middle,end" | sed 's/,[^,]*,/,NEW,/g' 
start,NEW,end
```

Is this what you mean? This simply matches the inner-most commas and replaces the text.

Depending how you want to handle strings with more than two commas, you could do something like this to match the outer-most instead:

```
$: echo "start,middle,end" | sed 's/,.*,/,NEW,/g'
start,NEW,end
```

Comment: What would you do to replace "end" with any other string?

Comment: echo "start,middle,end" | sed 's/,[^,]*$/,NEW/g' 
(This matches the last comma to the end of the line)

Comment: One more question. From this statement "execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(14, 145678, 789065);NEW", to replace 14 with a new ID, i tried  "  cat file1 | sed 's/(.*,/(27,/g'   "
execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(27, 789065);NEW. It is replacing till second comma. How to make it replace only till first comma. Something like this. execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(27, 145678, 789065);NEW

Comment: The default behavior of sed is to be "greedy" and match the largest expression that fits your criteria, so replacing all text between two commas is going to find the two outermost commas. A good solution would be to match any character except comma [^,] instead of just matching any character. So please try: sed 's/([^,]*,/(27,/g'

Comment: why is this statement not working any idea? I am taking clientID from user through command Line and storing it clientID variable like this. "read clientID                                                                                            
 echo $clientID                                                                                                   Unmerge="execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(27, 188039147, 572965000);NEW"                                                                     `echo $unmerge | sed 's/([^,]*,/($clientID,/g'`. It is not printing user given id?

Comment: You are using single-quotes, which means it is using the string $clientID rather than the value in the variable $clientID. It should work if you use double quotes. sed "s/([^,]*,/($clientID,/g"

Comment: You also have a typo using capitalized Unmerge to set the variable, but lowercase when echoing it.

Comment: If that is your actual use case, I don't think you need sed at all. You could just do: read clientID; echo $clientID; Unmerge="execute PKG_SP_MAINTENANCE.MoveAccount(${clientID}, 188039147, 572965000);NEW"; echo $Unmerge

Comment: Thanks @EdmCoff. I don't need sed at all in this case. Thank you so much for your prompt responses.